# Simulink - how to configure the appearance of a scope

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm working on generating some figures for a paper from a simulink model, and would prefer to use minimal work to produce them so I'm trying to configure a simulink scope to output the figures I want on its own. The problem is, while I can get colors and such all arranged well, I can't seem to figure out how to modify the spacing between the graphs in a scope showing multiple signals. What I have now looks like the below:

[image]

Notice how the two plots have different vertical scales (probably a consequence of having the time scale only on the bottom one), and that there's a large gap of unused space between the plots. This is a concern when trying to publish in a journal, since page space is at a premium and we need to make the information as dense as possible.

So, how can I tweak these margins and formatting? I've tried looking at all the settings I can find, but none seem to affect these parameters.

Comment: why not export/log the data and plot them as usual? Or export them to Latex and plot there?

Comment: @thewaywewalk This is my first time trying to do something professional (i.e. not a school assignment) with Simulink. I'm not familiar with what "like usual" is.

Comment: But you used the normal `plot` function of Matlab before? Have a look at [Signal Logging](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/exporting-signal-data-using-signal-logging.html) to learn how to actually export your data. A direct scope plot is not a good idea for a publication for reasons of reproducibility.